# ActiveRecord::Relation select records that have X number of associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to write an ActiveRecord query that will take an existing relation object `job_descriptions` and select from it those that have a certain number of `applications`. For example, I have `job_descriptions`, which has 50 records. I want to select only those records that have between 1 and 5 `applications`.

Here are my models:

```
class JobDescription < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :applications
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job_description
end
```

I've tried something like `job_descriptions.joins(:applications).group(:job_description_id).having('count(job_description_id) IN (?)', num_apps)` where `num_apps` is an array of integers `[1,2,3,4,5]`, but that didn't work. I can use the `joins` statement to get only those records with `applications`, but I need to select for the number of `applications`.

Comment: can you try this  JobDescription.joins(:applications).group_by(&:id).map{|l,m| [l, m.first.applications.count]}.delete_if{|k,v| (v > 5 || v < 1) }. im not sure if it is up to your work. this will return a array having arrays in it in which first is id and second is count of applications.  but this is quite heavy thing to be done. rather add column to your table job_desricptions saving count of applications and increment or decrement count upon creation/deletion of application by simply adding after_create and after_destroy  call backs to your application model

Comment: The counter_cache may work well for your case, but they are susceptible to errors. You did not specify the errors you were getting, but I think that you were close to finding the result you wanted. Perhaps this works?  `job_descriptions.joins(:applications).group(:id).having("count(*) BETWEEN 1 AND 5")`

Comment: Athar's suggestion seems really dense. I went with cache_counters because it seems much more readable. Even if the counts become out of sync, I can reset them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use `counter_cache` feature. To use it you need to add an extra `applications_count` column to JobDescription and then change your Application model to:

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job_description, counter_cache: true
end
```

At that point you will need to update all the records column. Easiest way to do this is:

```
JobDescription.reset_counter_cache(JobDescription.pluck(:id), :applications)
```

Naturally this is best to do within migration. After this point, rails will take care of keeping this column in sync with an actual number of associated objects. With this column in place your query changes to:

```
JobDescription.where('application_count >= ? AND application_count <= ?', 1, 5)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Seems much cleaner and reduces the number of queries. Thanks! I edited your `reset_counter` code. I modified it slightly to work for my use case and then ran it from the console.